# Greasemonkey script to remove <script> tag

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I want to remove a  tag in the very begining of the html file. That script redirects me to some other pages. I wrote a js and created a new userscript using grease monkey.

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
scripts[0].parentNode.removeChild (scripts[0]);
```

But this didn't worked. Since I'm new to grease monkey I don't know how to configure the script before executing that script tag. I tired adding @run-at document-start in the begining of the script. I cannot turn off the js since it contains a lot of ajax calls. So how this can be done with grease monkey? or is there any tools available to do the same?
The script tag is as follows.

```
 <script>alert('some text');location.href='new_url'</script>
 <!DOCTYPE html...>
 <html...
```

Comment: There is NoScript Firefox plugin.

Comment: Better use AdBlock for this. You can add custom rule to block any script.

Comment: @BrockAdams I tried your suggestion. But here the very first line is <script>location.href='url'</script>. So the page redirects before GM executes the script.

Comment: If you have set `@run-at document-start`, as in the linked answers, the solutions work fine. Beware that this is Firefox only (as is Greasemonkey).  Link to the target page if you still can't get it to work.  ... Edit: that's the very first line of the whole HTML file?  The solutions should still work, but I don't remember testing that scenario.   I'll give it a look-see.

Comment: Just tested the answers against an HTML file with just `<script>location.href='http://google.com'</script>` inside.  The answers still work flawlessly.  (FF 26 + GM 1.14).  Be sure to set a `@grant` other than `none`.

Answer (score -1):

Greasemonkey lets you add JavaScript code (called "user scripts") to any web page, which will run when its HTML code has loaded.
So when user scripts stat running ,the `<script>` have already run,maybe it is a little hard to do that.

Or use `$ wget url_you_want_to_visit`and remove the fist `<script>`.

Maybe you should install `wget` in your Windows OS.

Creat a file `a.bat`,and the content of it is like

```
wget url -O index.html&&perl remove_first_script.pl&&start  index.html;
```

and then use it in `cmd`like

```
a.bat the_url
```

Comment: How can I automate this? 1. $wget url  2. remove script(its easy) 3. render the output code in the browser. .. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score -2):

We can do it with a very simple line of jquery.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        NameForScript
// @include     http://example.com/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js
// @run-at      document-start
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==


    $($('script')[0]).html("alert('okay');");
```

Don't forget to add @run-at document-start. It will help to execute your GM script before execution of any js from the original page.

Comment: I believe that it is just luck that/if this works.  It depends on winning a very precise race condition.  Better to use one of the event-driven methods in the linked answers.